# Middleman build ignore swp files

Tags: vim, build, middleman, middleman-4, swp

How do I exclude swp files from the build process in Middleman?

Adding ignore `'*.swp'` to the `config.rb` doesn't work for me.

Comment: I moved all my .swp files to `~/.swps` so I didn't have to deal with this kind of thing, just one line in my `.vimrc` is ```set dir=~/.swps```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to use regex

`ignore /.*\.swp/` worked which looks for anything containing a `.swp` at the end.